# Jupyter doesn't work when "setup.py" is used

Tags: python, installation, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I tried to install Jupyter on my Mac (10.9).

Since I'm using a computer at the university and don't have permission to write in `/usr/local/bin`, I downloaded Ipython from [GitHub](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/releases) and typed `python3.4 setup.py install --user` on Terminal.

Though I didn't get any error while installing, Jupyter does not launch when I type `ipython notebook` (`ipython3 notebook` or `jupyter` were the same) and I got `command not found` error.

(I also tried to install via pip. However, pip does not work on my computer and I couldn't activate it using `ensurepip`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does pip not work? (insufficient privileges to write into system packages)?

Have you tried a virtual environments [Creation of virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)? They are very useful for managing your environment so that you have local packages and a local bin folder for things like `ipython`:

```
$ python3 -m venv my_venv
$ source my_venv/bin/activate
$ pip install ipython[all]
```

This will install into your `my_venv` environment.